# LINQ to entities Query group by and count from different tables

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, linq-to-entities

i have two tables

1) Logs

2) Jobs

structure of both are as follows

Logs :- id, Emailid, LogDate

```
  sampledata:-   1, a@a.com, jan24 1999
                 2, b@a.com, jan25 1999
                 3, a@a.com, jan25 1999  
                 4, c@a.com  jan26,1999
                 5, a@a.com  jan27,1999
```

Jobs :- jid, job_name, job_viewed_by

```
   sampledata:- j01, painter, a@a.com
                j02, teacher, a@a.com
                j01, painter, b@a.com
```

job_viewed_by is foreign key in jobs table and is related with Emailid in Logs table.

now i want a linq to entitites query which can give me

all Emailids from the logs tables who haved logged recently along with the no of jobs viewed (count of jobs) by them.

so as per above sample data my requirement is

a@a.com last logged on 27th jan.1999 and had viewed 2 jobs so far

b@a.com last logged on 24th jan.1999 had viewed 1 jobs so far

c@a.com last logged on 26th jan.1999. no jobs viewed

i know how to write it in SQL but i need to convert it using LinqtoEntities.

i tried a query but it give me number of recent logins rather than job counts.

```
    var q=   (from p in context.Logs
              from x in context.ViewedJobs.Where(v=>p.EmailId ==v.ViewedBy)
              group p by p.EmailId into grp
              select new{ EmailId = grp.Key, 
                          LastDate = grp.Max(g => g.LogDate),
                          Count=grp.Count() }).OrderByDescending(m=>m.LogDate);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just smiple to try:

```
var q = from p in context.Logs
        group p by p.Emailid into g
        select new 
        {
          EmailId=g.Key,
          LastDate= g.Max(x => x.LogDate),
          Count=context.ViewedJobs.Count(v=>v.ViewedBy==g.Key)
        };
```

Update Version:

```
var q = from p in context.Logs
        group p by p.Emailid into g
        join j in context.ViewedJobs 
        on g.Key equlas j.ViewedBy into leftGroup 
        select new 
        {
          EmailId=g.Key,
          LastDate= g.Max(x => x.LogDate),
          Count=leftGroup.Any()?leftGroup.Count():0
        };
```

Comment: Thank you it is working.can you explain me one thing how left join is handled in above case. as far as i know for left join i need to use defaultifempty. (sorry i am bit new to LinqToEntity)

Comment: @iGod here it is Group Join,not Left Join :)

Comment: got it i was thinking the same way as i posted my problem earlier.apply join on two tables then group and then how to count (??). sorry my mistake i didnt review my problem after seeing the solution